# How to override a jquery theme

Tags: jquery, css, background, tabs

I am using the Smoothness theme with Jquery tabs, and I want to override the look of the default theme on a few tabs, how would I go about doing that. I have tried the following:

```
$('#tab-id').css('background', '-moz-linear-gradient(center top, #999999, #494949 75%, #f3c84b)');
```

I call this from a click function when the user clicks on the tab.

I also tried `.addClass` too, but that also didn't override the smoothness theme.

Kind of at my wits end, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Edit the CSS file or override the class with `.removeClass()` and `.addClass()`.

Comment: Or override the css in a separate css file, where you mark your override as !important.

Comment: Note that for full compatibility you need more than just `-moz-linear-gradient` to get a gradient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just define the parameters in an external CSS files that are loaded AFTER your jQueryUI CSS sheet, if you use an ID on the tabs, you simply reference that ID in your CSS.

No need to style the CSS through JS!

Comment: I added an id and it did apply the style that I wanted to the tab, but I only want the style to be visible when the tab is selected.  Is there any way to do that with just CSS?

Comment: yes, you would need to specify the state of the tab, I believe it is something like `.active` or `.selected` you will have to use firebug or chrome developer tools to check. I haven't edited the tabs in awhile, just recalling.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding more `CSS Specificity` or add `!important` to your definitions

> ... If you have two (or more) conflicting CSS rules that point to the same
> element, there are some basic rules that a browser follows to
> determine which one is most specific and therefore wins out ...

http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssadvanced/specificity/

> ... Specificity determines, which CSS rule is applied by the browsers ...
>
> ... Apart from Floats, the CSS Specificity is one of the most difficult
> concepts to grasp in Cascading Stylesheets. The different weight of
> selectors is usually the reason why your CSS-rules don’t apply to some
> elements, although you think they should have ...

http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/