# How do you override CSS applied by jQuery UI theme properly?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8360694/how-to-override-a-jquery-theme) (and common sense) I should be able to change characteristics of a jQueryUI Widget such as a button after load.  For example, set the background of a particular Button Red.

When I try using css or even using the `$('.selector').css({'background-color': 'Red'})` after the .button() call, the button flashes red on load and goes back to the jQuery UI theme.  How do I stop jQuery UI from overriding the overrides?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery UI supplies a neat callback for when it's done creating the element. That's where you'd want to do the color change.

```
$( ".selector" ).button({
    create: function(event, ui) {
    $('.selector').css({'background-color': 'Red'})
}
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you selecting for the `button` element or its child `span` tag? This example works for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/8UvZ5/

Comment: no, I was setting the button's background itself, incorrectly.  thanks for this info.  Besides button, I was looking for a more generic way of overriding jQuery UI css.

Comment: The more generic way would be to override them using CSS rules, not with javascript, as the answers in your link mentions.